# Generic way to drop columns that are not needed for learning (in python using pandas df)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

By generic; I mean to say that I do not know the name of a column that needs to be dropped ahead of pulling in the file. Examples I have found; assume that you know the name of a column you wish to drop. Those familiar with the PlayTennis data set are probably used to seeing:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"Outlook": [Sunny,Cloudy,Rainy], "Temp":[Hot,Cold],
"Humidity":[high,low]...})
```

However in my class we get a first column 'Days' so something like:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"Days":[D1,D2,...,D14],"Outlook": [Sunny,Cloudy,Rainy], "Temp":[Hot,Cold],"Humidity":[high,low]...})
```

Obviously, looking at this I would want to drop the 'Days' column:

```
df.drop(columns=['Days'], inplace=True)
```

The problem is that playtennis is just a sample dataset and in the actual dataset the column I may need to drop for the same reason as 'Days' will not be called Days. I need a way to drop the useless column by some method that can see that the number of unique values in a column and understands its too many to be useful (Edit: Meaning it overfits, if I have 30 instances and 30 days the model will try to predict a result based on what day it is and therefore, useless for predictability); Before I read it into my machine learning algorithm.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_train = pd.read_csv("assets\playtennis.csv") # read in data
df_train.head() # see first 5

# get a list of attribute excluding the class label (e.g.,PlayTennis)
def attributes (df,label):
    return df.columns.drop(label).values.tolist()
    
    
def trash(df,attr,label):
    # Do something to trash useless columns
    df.drop(columns=[x],inplace=True)
    
class_label = df_train.columns[-1] # class label in the last column
attr = attributes(df_train,class_label)
trash(df_train,attr,class_label)
```

I only have about 6 weeks working with python so please forgive(and point out) syntax errors.

Comment: What's the problem?  identifying the column name, or passing that name as variable to the `drop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, it was not quite obvious why you want to drop Days column in your dataset.
I assume that you want to drop a feature with distinct values on each row or too many unique entries such that the feature has no predictability to your testing label.
You can get the unique values of a column (eg. 'name') by calling `df['name'].unique()`, and call `len()` on top of that to get the number of unique values.

I would suggest you have a threshold for highest the proportion of unique values before you drop that column.

```
def trash(df, attr, label, threshold=0.8):
    for col in att:
        proportion = len(df.col.unique())/len(df)
        if proportion >= threshold:
            df.drop([col], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, and you assumed correctly. That indeed is why I needed to drop a column.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the data, e.g. with `pd.read_csv`, you can only load the columns you want with argument `usecols=[list-of-columns-i-care-about]`. That way you don't need to drop them.

Comment: Thank you for the response. While this is useful it isn't what I need because it is not generic. For example I would need to know what columns to drop before hand meaning I need to read each file to make the 'list-of-columns-i-care-about'

Comment: you'll either need to know the columns you want, or the columns you don't. My solution assumes you know the columns you want, so I'm confused why you claim "I would need to know what columns to drop before hand"

Comment: I need to drop columns on criteria other than the name of the column. Essentially, when it becomes apparent the column will not provide value for predicting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to further define what `understands its too many to be useful` means.

As a starting point you can calculate the number of unique values per column with `nunique`.

You can use that value to drop columns.
For example, this drops all columns with more than three unique values.

```
df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.nunique() > 3])
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g'],
    'col3': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'col4': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
})


df.nunique()
col1    10
col2     7
col3     2
col4     3


df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.nunique() > 3], inplace=True)
  col3  col4
0    a     1
1    a     1
2    a     1
3    a     1
4    a     2
5    b     2
6    b     2
7    b     3
8    b     3
9    b     3
```